# error in integrate : 'upper' must be of length one

Tags: r, function, integrate, cdf

```
fl=function(q,a=-23.0344,b=10.0249) (b/q)*dnorm((a+b*log(q)),0,1)

Fl=function(h) integrate(fl,lower=0,upper=h)$value

Fz=function(z){
  integrand=function(x){
    Fl((x-z)*10)*fl(10*x)
  }
  1-10*integrate(integrand,0,Inf)$value
}
library(GoFKernel)
inv=inverse(Fz,lower=-100000,upper=100000)
```

why do i get this error?
"Error in integrate(fl, lower = 0, upper = h) :
'upper' must be of length one"

how can i solve it?

Comment: I used https://www.mycompiler.io/new/r to run your code and I got the following error: 'Error: unexpected symbol in: "integrand=function(x){F((x-z)*10)f" Execution halted [Execution complete with exit code 1]'

Comment: hi i made a mistake i'll correct it

Comment: now i got this error:"Error in integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = h) : 'upper' must be of length one"

Comment: Update or code or add breaking points to your code as you validate line by line. You are getting syntax errors not logical ones. As long as you get better with R they'll disappear.

Comment: would you please correct my code?

Comment: I am not proficient with R. I am just stating the obvious. If you update your code the community will certainly help as long as you display effort into solving those minor problems.

Comment: First, `F` is a keyword in R, which is the error that @Miguel Cardoso ran into first. (Change that variable name to avoid problems.) I'm guessing that you're using the library `GoFKernel`. There are MANY libraries with these functions, though. (That information needs to be in your question next time.) Your function currently named `F` is returning a list (you need `$value`). You end up with 21 values for x, so that's what you're sending to `F`'s `upper` from the function `F1`.  You could add something like `if(length(h) > 1) h = h[length(h)]`, which would take the last value.

Comment: i'm so appreciate for your help @Kat . I edit my code. but i still get error . i even use if(length(h) > 1) h = h[length(h)] but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, when you run `integrate()`, it tries to evaluate the integrand for a vector of values.

```r
> traceback()
9: stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p)))
8: stopifnot(length(lower) == 1, length(upper) == 1)
7: integrate(fl, lower = 0, upper = h) at #1
6: Fl((x - z) * 10) at #3
5: f(x, ...)
4: (function (x) 
   f(x, ...))(c(1, 233.065168689948, 0.00429064542600244, 38.2988398013854, 
   0.0261104515224461, 13.7999516465199, 0.072464022020844, 6.73787740945863, 
   0.148414691931943, 3.83193602946711, 0.260964690514175, 2.36612585866545, 
   0.422631787036055, 1.52456705113438, 0.655923922306948))
3: integrate(integrand, 0, Inf) at #5
2: f(lower)
1: inverse(Fz, lower = -1e+05, upper = 1e+05)
```

I tried vectorizing the `Fl` function (there are a variety of ways of doing this: `Vectorize`, `Map`, `purrr::map`, `vapply()`, ... but I used a good old-fashioned `for` loop)

```r
Fl <- function(h) {
   res <- numeric(length(h))
   for (i in seq_along(h)) {  
      res[i] <- integrate(fl,lower=0,upper=h[i])$value
   }
   res
}
```

Once this is fixed we hit.

> Error in integrate(fl, lower = 0, upper = h[i]) :  non-finite function value

We also get a warning that `log(q)` is being called for negative values of `q`, which will produce an `NaN` which will mess everything up downstream.

We can set `options(error = browser)`, but I had trouble with that.  Instead, I set up a checkpoint if negative values of `q` are used (which will inevitably lead to trouble):

```r
fl=function(q,a=-23.0344,b=10.0249) {
   if (any(q <= 0)) browser()
   (b/q)*dnorm((a+b*log(q)),0,1)
}
```

When I get thrown in the browser I try:

```r
print(q)
 [1] -499995.000  -13046.605 -986943.395  -67467.642 -932522.358 -160293.613
 [7] -839696.387 -283299.470 -716690.530 -425558.575 -574431.425   -2171.397
[13] -997818.603  -34920.905 -965069.095 -109590.041 -890399.959 -218619.246
[19] -781370.754 -352800.041 -647189.959
```

So you'll have to think about what you're doing (TBH I haven't tried to figure out the **logic** of your code) and whether you're inadvertently evaluating expressions over negative ranges when they're not allowed.